# Switch integer to string

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the System.out.print on the same line. I want to have the cases as just days (case 0: "Sunday") so I can write System.out.println( "Today is "+ day + " and the future day is " + m1) but when I try this, I get the case number instead of the string (Today is 0 and the future day is 0). I think there's a better way to write the logic compared to the way I have it:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HomeWork3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Sun = 0, Mon = 1, Tue = 2, Wed = 3, Thurs = 4, Fri = 5, Sat = 6 ");
        System.out.print("\nEnter today's number: ");
        int day = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the number of days that elapsed since today:  ");
        int n1 = input.nextInt();


        //String strD = Integer.toString(day); 

        switch (day){
        case 0: System.out.println("Today is Sunday"); 
        break;
        case 1: System.out.println("Today is Monday");
        break;
        case 2: System.out.println("Today is Tuesday");
        break;
        case 3: System.out.println("Today is Wednesday");
        break;
        case 4: System.out.println("Today is Thursday");
        break;
        case 5: System.out.println("Today is Friday");
        break;
        case 6: System.out.println("Today is Saturday");
        break;
        }
        int m1 = ((day + n1)% 7);

        switch (m1){
        case 0: System.out.println("The future day is Sunday");
        break;
        case 1: System.out.println("The future day is Monday");
        break;
        case 2: System.out.println("The future day is Tuesday");
        break;
        case 3: System.out.println("The future day is Wednesday");
        break;
        case 4: System.out.println("The future day is Thursday");
        break;
        case 5: System.out.println("The future day is Friday");
        break;
        case 6: System.out.println("The future day is Saturday");
        break;
        }
        //String strD = Integer.toString(day);

        //System.out.println(strD + " this might work " + n1);

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

Sun = 0, Mon = 1, Tue = 2, Wed = 3, Thurs = 4, Fri = 5, Sat = 6 
Enter today's number: 2
Enter the number of days that elapsed since today:  5
Today is Tuesday
The future day is Sunday

Comment: "OUTPUT" means "output wanted" ?

Comment: declare to strings `String currentDay` and `String futureDay`. Instead of printing directly in your cases set those two strings to the correct value and print once at the very and `System.out.Println("Today is "+currentday+". The future day is "+futureDay);`

Comment: You are wondering why if you print `day` you get an integer but you get it like `int day = input.nextInt();`. So  would suggest you to understand your code. If you wont to print it at the end, use your switch to set a value into a `String dayText` (to keep your code)

Comment: you might want to use an array

Comment: "OUTPUT" meant that is what I was getting from the logic.

Comment: I used the switch but it did not work. I commented it out in my code. Unless I didn't write it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is when you change the `println()` in the first `switch`-block to `print()` and add a space to your text.

A second version is to define two Strings and set the values in the `switch`-blocks:

```
String today;
switch (day){
    case 0: today = "Sunday"; 
    break;
```

and so on and also

```
String futureday;
switch (m1){
    case 0: futureday = "Sunday"; 
    break;
```

and so on. At last you have your desired output:

```
System.out.println("Today is "+ today + " and the future day is " + futureday);
```

But the most elegant way is to define an array of weekdays:

```
String[] days = {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday"};
```

So you can delete your `switch`-blocks and simply write:

```
System.out.println("Today is "+ days[day] + " and the future day is " + days[m1]);
```

**Hint:** You have to initialize `day` and `futureday`. And you should check, that `day` is < 7 to prevent an IndexOutOfBounds-Exception.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following:

```
String[] days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
int m1 = ((day + n1)% 7);
String output = String.format("Today is %s, the future day is %s", days[day], days[m1]);
System.out.println(output);
```

(Obviously you need to ensure day<7)

Comment: I like this, but I'm trying to get it to work with a switch command.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply using the built-in [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum:

```
int day = 4;
System.out.println("Today is " + DayOfWeek.of(day)
    .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault()));
```

Output:

```
Today is Thursday
```

---

But if you want to use a switch statement, I'd say, add a layer of abstraction, to simplify the problems you need to solve. e.g. make a method that takes and `int` and returns the day of the week as a `String`:

```
public static String getWeekDay(int dayNumber) {
    switch(dayNumber) {
        case 0: return "Sunday";
        case 1: return "Monday";
        case 2: return "Tuesday";
        ...
    }

    throw new IllegalArguemntException("Invalid day number: " + dayNumber);
}
```

And use that to create the output:

```
System.out.println("Today is " + getWeekDay(day));
```

Comment: @AxelH Meh, googling "java int to week day" yields the `DayOfWeek` doc at #1. Could have gotten there himself. Some people just like to ask others, rather than google.

Comment: I googled 1st. I asked the question here after I tried everything I found. So, I'm not taking the "some people just like to asks" personally, but someone else might. Soft skills are needed when dealing with people who are trying to learn.

Comment: @Drolltv65 See my update. I wasn't judging by the way, It's also nice to ask other people.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to associate int and String you can use a map

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);
    //add all days into the map with their key (number)
    HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map.put(0, "Sunday");
    map.put(1, "Monday");
    map.put(2, "Tuesday");
    map.put(3, "Wednesday");
    map.put(4, "Thursday");
    map.put(5, "Friday");
    map.put(6, "Saturday");

    //Printing all days
    for(int key : map.keySet()){
        System.out.print(key+"="+map.get(key)+", ");
    }
    System.out.print("\nEnter today's number: ");
    int day = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the number of days that elapsed since today:  ");
    int n1 = input.nextInt();

    n1  = ((day + n1)% 7);

    System.out.println("Today is "+map.get(day) + ", the future day is " + map.get(n1));

}
```

It allows you to get back the value which corresponds to the key entered with rhe scanner

Comment: why not `String[] days = {"Sunday", ..."Saturday"};`? It easier for this case

Comment: @AxelH you can too, but I'm so used to Map that it has becomed always my first idea to came out :D bu yes when the keys are integer, starting to 0, an array is better, but it allows to show different possibilites